# Calculate percentage of used disk space in grafana which is using zabbix as datasource

Tags: grafana, zabbix

I am using zabbix 5.4 and grafana 8.0.6
I have free disk space data in terabytes and used disk space in terabytes in Zabbix
Now I have to calculate the percentage of used disk space in grafana how to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

used % = (used/(used+free))* 100

Comment: where should I add this formula in grafana

Comment: yes, you need to write prometheus query in grafana for this.

Comment: But my datasource is not Prometheus its zabbix